# highlighting in-line equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, highlighting

I am using \hl to highlight in-line equations but it is not working properly for some cases. Please see the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7

\begin{document}

\hl{For example, {$TW_{ij}$} where {$j=\alpha$} (stopping the use of a staff member after doing task {$i$}) is determined based on the difference of {$ES_s+mO$} and {$ET_i+ST_i$}. Whatever this difference is smaller, the transition from task {$i$} to {$j$} becomes more desirable (a higher probability).}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `...{$<math>$}...` for math content and not just `...$<math>$...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't need linebreaking within the math you can put it in a box

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7

\begin{document}

\hl{For example, \mbox{$TW_{ij}$} where \mbox{$j=\alpha$} (stopping the use of a
  staff member after doing task \mbox{$i$}) is determined based on the
  difference of \mbox{$ES_s+mO$} and \mbox{$ET_i+ST_i$}. Whatever this
  difference is smaller, the transition from task \mbox{$i$} to \mbox{$j$}
  becomes more desirable (a higher probability).}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wrap your math content into a group. Just set it as-is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7

\begin{document}

\hl{For example, $TW_{ij}$ where $j = \alpha$ (stopping the use of a staff member after doing task $i$) 
is determined based on the difference of $ES_s + mO$ and $ET_i + ST_i$. Whatever this difference is 
smaller, the transition from task $i$ to $j$ becomes more desirable (a higher probability).}

\end{document}
```